# How thread sleep works internally in java?

Tags: java

It may be a dumb question but i have researched it alot and i am not getting any satisfactory knowledge.
Can anyone help me to understand?

my code

```
public class sleepclass extends Thread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sleepclass t1 = new sleepclass();
        sleepclass t2 = new sleepclass();
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e);

            }
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
```

Now as per the output i can see both thread gone to a sleep state. and both comes after at the same time

My question is :

1 . Since sleep is a static method how both works and sleep at same time? (explain in layman please).

2. Can i sleep only t1 and left t2 to run?

Comment: It's a static method -- and it blocks the current thread that it is called in

Comment: Ah thanks, I was looking for a duplicate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Thread.sleep()` sleeps the **current thread**. It has no effect elsewhere.

If you want one thread to sleep and one not in your current code, you would have to have some kind of indicator to control it. Such as a `boolean` flag which you would then check:

```
if(shouldSleep) {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

Otherwise all threads will execute the same code, and all threads will sleep for 5 seconds.

Comment: Not your down-voter, but probably don't need this answer

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels can you explain it in more better way.. just asking, what sleep does internally? i mean some kind of setTimeout? in javascript mechanism if yes can we sleep any api call too?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes, well I answered for the "how do I make one thread sleep and not the other" part. Otherwise the dupe would've been enough (or if I had found it when I was looking for dupes).

Comment: @alessio.rian does it really matter? The thread sleeps (stops executing code). It's an internal mechanism that you shouldn't be too concerned about, especially if you're a beginner.